# Pyspark get +1 every time if token in array

Tags: pyspark

I have next df table in pyspark:

```
+---------------------------
|id  |list_tokens          |     
+---------------------------
|id1 |['A','A','B']        |
|id2 |['D','P','E','P','P']|
|id3 |['B','C']            |
|id4 |['A','C']            |
+---------------------------
```

I have compiled a list of unique tokens and selected the most popular.
For example I have list:

```
[A, B, C]
```

I want to make a table with [A, B, C] tokens as rows and id user as a columns and fill it +1 if list of tokens for this user contain tokens in list most popular tokens and 0 otherwise.
Example:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+-------+
|      token|  id1      | id2     |id3     |id4    |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+-------+
|A          |2          |0        |0       |1      |
|B          |1          |0        |1       |0      |
|C          |0          |0        |1       |1      |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode` to split the array into rows and `pivot` to count for each values.

```py
target = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df.select(f.col('id'), f.explode('list_tokens').alias('token')) \
  .withColumn('filter', f.array([f.lit(t) for t in target])) \
  .filter('array_contains(filter, token)') \
  .groupBy('id').pivot('token').count().fillna(0) \
  .show()

+---+---+---+---+
| id|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+---+
|id3|  0|  1|  1|
|id1|  2|  1|  0|
|id4|  1|  0|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```